# Writing regex to find consecutive character 'o'

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a regex to detect the a repeating `o` at the end of a word. Here's my regex;

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*[o]\\1+");
```

For example if i have a word `zoo`, `masoo` or `kjuoo`, it should be detected and if there's a word called `eoop`, `loop` or `snoop` it should not get detected, as the It should ONLY detect words ending with `oo` (2 `o`'s)

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your regex to

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(o)\\1+");
```

since to create groups you need to use `()`, not `[]`

demo:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(o)\\1+");
for (String s: new String[]{"zoo","masoo","kjuoo","loop","snoop"}){
    System.out.println(s+":\t"+p.matcher(s).matches());
}
```

output:

```
zoo:    true
masoo:  true
kjuoo:  true
loop:   false
snoop:  false
```

Comment: I guess i will also have to add `$`

Comment: @sharonHwk I don't think so. Are you trying to find words in text that should match, or you already have selected words (like in my example) and you need to test them if they are "correct" ones?

Comment: snoop returns true, if i don't use $ at the end of the regex

Comment: @sharonHwk. If you use `Matcher.matches()`, you would need to build regex to match complete string, in which case `^` and `$` are redundant, as `matches()` implicitly matches at the beginning. On contrary, if you use `Matcher.find()`, you can build regex to match a part of the string, in which case, you have to explicitly give `$`, or `^` whatever is relevant.

Comment: @RohitJain We don't need to invoke `matches` on every string, but as in my example we can use already created Pattern, wrap selected string in Matcher, and invoke `matches` on it so no regex rebuild will happen.

Comment: @Pshemo. Ah! you misunderstood my comment. I meant to say, with matches, you have to make sure your regex is created to match the string from beginning to end, and not just a substring.

Comment: @sharonHwk As you can see in my example `snoop` returns false for me. Could you show how you are using regex? You can give link to http://pastebin.com/. Also if you want to `find` with few `o` at end of word you should probably use `\b` instead `$` if word is placed inside your string.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, sorry, by bad. Anyway if we want to use `find` shouldn't OP be using `\b` instead `$` in case words are placed inside string like `ab nooooo cd`?

Comment: @Pshemo. Yeah `$` will not work if words are in middle. But, if you want to match `oo` in the middle, `\b` too won't work. You need - `(?<!o)oo(?!o)`, to restrict match to just 2 `o's`. Using `\b` will stop matching a string like - `abcooasd`, which is fine.

Answer (score 4):

You should add a `$` at the end, to match it at the end. And you need to capture the `o`, instead of using *parenthesis*. A *character class* doesn't capture the match, and `\\1` will give you nothing in that case.

Also, since you are only worried about `o's` at the end, you can remove `.*` from the beginning and use [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) instead of [`Matcher#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29). So, your regex should be:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(o)\\1+$");
```

or, you can use `{n,m}` quantifier with `o` directly, keeping 2nd argument empty, to match 2 or more `o`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("o{2,}$");
```

---

> It should ONLY detect words ending with oo (2 o's)

If you want to match just 2 `o's`, then you can remove the quantifier `+` from the backreference:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(o)\\1$");
```

or simply use a different quantifier - `{n}`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("o{2}$");
```

---

**Sample code:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("o{2}$");
String[] words = {"zoo", "kjuoo", "snoop", "loop"};

for (String word: words) {
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(word);
    System.out.println(word + " : " + matcher.find());  // Use `find()`
}
```

**Output:**

```
zoo : true
kjuoo : true
snoop : false
loop : false
```

Comment: Or use `o{2,}$` to match 2 or more `o` at the end.

Comment: OP will probably have to use `matches` so text will have to match entire regex, so `^` and `$` will be redundant then. Anyway nice idea with `{2,}`.

Comment: @Pshemo. Yeah, I should've quoted to use Matcher.find().

Answer (score 0):

```
oo(?!\w)
```

This will match `oo` as there is no character after it, you can test this [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Works for all your provided examples.